# How to generate a single Account SAS for both container.listBlobs() and blob.exists()

Tags: java, azure, account, sas-token

I'm developing a Java application which executes the following methods with Account SAS (Shared Access Signature) URI:

```
CLoudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("tmp/test.json");
blob.exists();
blob.openInputStream();
blob.delete();
container.exists();
container.listBlobs().iterator().next();
container.getDirectoryReference("tmp/").listBlobs().iterator().next()
```

But, I could not find a way to generate a single Account SAS to support all methods listed above.

1. Account SAS generated with SharedAccessAccountResourceType.OBJECT:

Executes successfully:

```
CLoudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("tmp/test.json");
blob.exists();
blob.openInputStream();
blob.delete();
```

Fails with an error code: AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch

```
container.exists();
container.listBlobs().iterator().next();
container.getDirectoryReference("tmp/").listBlobs().iterator().next()
```

2. Account SAS generated with SharedAccessAccountResourceType.CONTAINER:

Executes successfully:

```
container.exists();
container.listBlobs().iterator().next();
container.getDirectoryReference("tmp/").listBlobs().iterator().next()
```

Fails with an error code: AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch

```
CLoudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("tmp/test.json");
blob.exists();
blob.openInputStream();
blob.delete();
```

3. Account SAS generated with SharedAccessAccountResourceType.SERVICE
   fails with an error code: AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch for all methods above.

Is there any way to generate a single Account SAS which work for all following methods?

```
CLoudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("tmp/test.json");
blob.exists();
blob.openInputStream();
blob.delete();
container.exists();
container.listBlobs().iterator().next();
container.getDirectoryReference("tmp/").listBlobs().iterator().next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea just add the right permissions on the blob and container resources. Note that list is different from the create.

You can find it here

[image]

And then add permissions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For `listing blobs` in a blob container, you would need to set `resource type` as `Container`. The permission you would need would be `List`.

For `checking if blob exists`, you would need to set `resource type` as `Object`. The permission you would need would be `Read`.

For `deleting blob`, you would need to set the permission as `Delete`. The resource type would still be `Object`.

Since you're working with just Blob Storage, the `service type` would be just `Blob`.

To summarize:

- **Service Type**: Blob
- **Resource Types**: Container (for listing blobs), and Object (for checking blob's existence and deleting blob)
- **Permissions**: List, Read, and Delete

With this you should be able to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Setting both resource types resolved the issue:

```
sasAccountPolicy.setResourceTypes(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessAccountResourceType.OBJECT, SharedAccessAccountResourceType.CONTAINER));
```

(The application which I'm developing also has to generate SAS URI.)

Thanks.